# Understanding multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to get my head around multithreading.

For simple tasks the easiest way I have found is to do this:

```
new Thread(delegate()
{
    Console.Writeline("doing stuff here");

}).Start();

new Thread(delegate()
{
    Console.Writeline("doing other stuff here");

}).Start();
```

What I'm wondering is if I call a method within my two threads, can this cause a conflict:

```
new Thread(delegate()
{
    dostuff();

}).Start();

new Thread(delegate()
{
    dostuff();

}).Start();


private void dostuff()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do Stuff Here");
}
```

Comment: only if the method refers to/modifies non-local resources. writing to the console could be consider a shared resource...

Comment: What kind of conflict are you thinking of?  Essentially there's no difference between your two programs, but the use of threads (regardless of method calls) can certainly cause various problems. (For example, you can't guarantee which method will write to the console first in either of your samples).

Comment: One more remark - once you've grasped the concepts of multithreading, thread-safety and race conditions, you will want to read on `Task` which is in many cases more useful/less painful to use than plain `Thread`s - e.g. Task allows to execute some code in your UI/main thread *after* the "worker code" has completed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can only cause a conflict if you are sharing a variable, like maybe a class static or a global between those threads in that `dostuff` method.

All variables local to that method only are safe, its the ones that you may be sharing you will have to use a lock on to protect against data races.

Also your console is a shared resource which would need coordination to write to, if you want it to be ordered properly.

Answer (score 3):

### Atomic operations

This particular case won't cause a conflict as it's basically doing exactly the same thing as the first case ([and because `Console.Write` line is thread-safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)). Only when they are dealing with shared objects, an example of this is:

```
private int number = 0;

public void RunThreads()
{
    new Thread(delegate()
    {
        Increment();

    }).Start();

    new Thread(delegate()
    {
        Increment();

    }).Start();
}

private void Increment()
{
    number += number;
}
```

At the end of this, `number` could be either `1` or `2` depending on the order in which the threads execute. This is because reading `number` and setting `number` are ***atomic operations*** (ie. reading and setting together aren't) and therefore could possibly be interleaved like so:

```
Thread1: Read number as 0
Thread2: Read number as 0
Thread1: Set number as 0+1
Thread2: Set number as 0+1
```

Resulting in `number == 1` after both threads finish.

### Locking a critical section

To fix a case like this you can create a 'lock object' with the [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword to only allow one thread in to that *critical section* at a time.

```
private object mylock = new Object();

public void RunThreads()
{
    // ...
}

private void Increment()
{
    lock (mylock)
    {
        number += number;
    }
}
```

Locking like this obviously slows the execution however as only one thread is allowed into the critical section at one time and the other(s) are blocked.

Answer (score 3):

As with everything the answer is - It Depends ...

It depends on what is happening inside your dostuff() method.  Are the things you are interacting with Threadsafe - [This is Required Reading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

You can block threads in your code like this:

```
var myLock = new object();
```

Then make use of this in threading scenarios like:

```
lock(myLock)
{
    // do things in here
}
```

Comment: Joseph Albahari is really very good, he writes the C# In A Nutshell series of books.

Comment: +1 the first answer that suggests further reading, which IMHO is key for the OP